# Cin doesn't wait in a joined thread when working with promises and futures

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with futures and promises and constructed a simple, although stupid example. In fact very stupid, but let's leave it.

I cannot understand why the following program doesn't wait for the input from user. It prints the slogan for the user to provide some number, but it doesn't wait. I know that similar problems were discussed here and on other forums and usually the answer was that the user forgot to join the thread. But I am joining the thread and even though this code doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

shared_ptr<promise<int>> prom;

auto fun()
{
    prom = make_shared<promise<int>>();
    auto ret = prom->get_future(); 
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    thread t{ [] {
        while(!prom){
            cout << "Waiting for a promise" << endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); 
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); 
        cout << "OK, got the promise, now enter some value: " << endl;
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        prom->set_value(val);
    }};

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s); 
    auto fut = fun();    
    t.join();    
    int v = fut.get();        
    cout << "You entered: " << v << endl;      
}
```

Working example:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/AzTQer4rNkJcMBC7

Comment: I dont think the online editors will allow an infinite wait on the user input, if you specify the user input on `stdin` it does show correctly the value. Are you running this locally or only on the online editior?

Comment: Only in online editor. Hm... maybe that's the problem. I'll try locally. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me locally.

Comment: @YotKay then thats your problem, I have it working fine.

Comment: You are using a regular (non-atomic, unsynchronised) object `prom` in two threads simultaneously. It cannot possibly work. The fact that it points to some kind of object vaguely related to parallel processing is irrelevant.

Comment: It works fine locally. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @n.m. - I know that prom is unsynchronized, I just wanted to test the promises and futures, that's all.

Comment: You cannot test anything by invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh, don't exaggerate :-) I know that there was a risk that two threads (main and the one I created) would try to read/write the 'prom' at the same time, but I accepted this risk in this small excercise, which I did to better understand the mechanism of futures and promises. I would probably run this code many times to see the error related to this race condition. I just accepted this in this very scenario of checking something out. That's all :-)

Comment: So you decided to test the behavior of something you want to learn about by guessing at the behavior of something else that you know to be incorrect? Just do it right.

Comment: Oh please, sometimes you want to do something quickly, not especially 100% correctly :-) Relax ;-)